# Allow zooming within iFrame but not on page in iOS

Tags: ios, css, html

I have a simple page with

```
<meta name="viewport" id="extViewportMeta" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

on it, with everything sized nicely to display on an iPhone.

But when I put an iframe on that page, everything inside the iFrame is not zoomable, and scales to the size of the parent page.

How can I allow zooming within the iframe only, without messing with the rest of my page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are requesting is unfortunately not possible.

First off, in you 'viewport' meta tag, your "content" attribute is specifying that the user of your website CAN NOT zoom at all. That is what the **'user-scalable=no'** dictates.

Also, your **maximum-scale and minimum-scale is set to 1**, so even if you remove the 'user-scalable=no', the zooming would disabled by the fact that you there is no scaling range for the user to zoom within.

So to enable zooming for the user you will have to remove the user-scalable=no and set different min and max scale values.

See this link to better understand the settings for the 'viewport' meta tag:

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

Secondly, since your 'viewport' meta tag is set on your 'parent' page, these settings apply to anything within that page, i.e the iframe too. Whether the iframe has a different meta 'viewport' tag specifying different settings does not matter since it lives within and abides by the settings of its parent.

Comment: This is possible via jQuery. Bind the zooming and panning events to not do anything when zooming and panning outside the divs that you allow zooming and panning. Then for the divs you want to allow zooming and panning, you can use plugins like [Panzoom](http://timmywil.github.io/jquery.panzoom/demo/) that use "CSS3 transforms and matrix functions" to allow for zooming and panning.

Comment: can we disable the application of parent settings to a particular child element ?

Answer (score 4):

This is possible via jQuery. Bind the zooming and panning events to not do anything when zooming and panning outside the divs that you allow zooming and panning. Then for the divs you want to allow zooming and panning, you can use plugins like [Panzoom](http://timmywil.github.io/jquery.panzoom/demo/) that use "CSS3 transforms and matrix functions" to allow for zooming and panning.

Comment: Panzoom works great with cordova apps with very little effort.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as iOS does not allow zooming - you just can scroll through your iFrame.
Is this an external site, that you own? If so, change the CSS code and add it the to viewport like in your question on the top. 
Alternatively, you can load the data with PHP. You will surely find a solution for your problem - if not, feel free to ask follow-up questions.

Comment: But that's the thing - it *does* allow zooming. That's the point of pinching and zooming.

Comment: I cannot say why they do not allow it. I think that it is weird and hard, if you are an User. If you are on an Website and this website allows zooming (you do not allow zooming, but iOS is doing no differences) and the iframe fills the whole screen, you cannot go out (if you know what I mean). It is a website in a website.                Hope that I have understood your comment (if not comment again ;) )

Comment: I'm still confused. iOS Safari does allow zooming. Go to a website like http://newspaperclub.com on an iPhone and you can zoom happily.

Comment: Right, but not in an iFrame. The Website newpaperclub.com works without frames (read the source code). You can ask for an access on their Database (maybe MySQL) and then load your content with PHP in your Website. This is what i want to do in my next app :D

Comment: No, newspaper club was an example. Open http://jsfiddle.net/7wZsj/embedded/result/ on an iPhone and you *can* zoom.

Comment: I believe if you add `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">` to the `head` of jsfiddle document, the newspaperclub.com won't zoom.
The point is that `user-scalable=no` disables browser zoom for nested iframes too.