# How to use Kendo-zoomable view and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have an AngularJs mobile web application.

I use this meta tag to give the application its mobile look and feel.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

But in my application, I have an IFRAME where I want to display some content that is so big, that I would like for the user to be able to zoom on the content.

According to this: [Allow zooming within iFrame but not on page in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678454/allow-zooming-within-iframe-but-not-on-page-in-ios) that is not possible when using the above meta tag.

But then I discovered this component from Kendo: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/view/zoomable.html

Does anyone know how to use it together with AngularJS?

(I have a library called angular-kendo.js that I use for datepicker and combobox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got no replies.

So I resolved my problem by using a library called hammer.js.
Here is a good article: http://creativedroplets.com/html5-and-multitouch-hammer-js/