# Pinch to zoom cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

how do you implement pinch to zoom for a cordova android project

I have a iframe in which I am loading my src
and I want to implement pinch to zoom on the iframe because it is occupying the whole screen

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678454/allow-zooming-within-iframe-but-not-on-page-in-ios). it refers to an iOS situation, not android, but the main idea stands.

Comment: @Merlin that other question appears to be referring to a website, rather than an app

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24389605/50447

Comment: You may want to check out the hammer.js library: http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/. It will give you the ability to handle pinch notifications (along with a bunch of other gestures) and then you can manipulate your page content appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

To be precise you can achieve pinch to zoom in two ways

> 1. If you open the image in a native container which allows zoom and pinch - the performance is far better, here you might need a Cordova plugin which can do that for you, i found https://github.com/keensoft/FullScreenImage-Cordova-Plugin but i think it only opens up the image in full screen natively but doesnt allow pinch and zoom , you can try
> 2. If you dont use a plugin which means the image is shown inside the webview, for which you either write code for touch events or simply use hammer.js which allows this.

Comment: does it mean that with hammer.js you can achieve pinch zooming in a cordova project, cross platform to at least Android and iOS without requiring to develop natively to a specific platform?