# Is it possible to pinch to zoom in cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, multi-touch, pinchzoom

There is not a lot of information on this, and the little that I have been able to find is very vague and unhelpful.  I imply want a page in my cordova/phonegap app to have an image that can be pinched on to zoom in and pan around.  Is this possible and if so, How do I do it?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but whole page will be zoomed. Image including any text or button, do you want that?

Comment: Could I put it in an iframe?

Comment: Then you've to try that out by yourself. I'm giving you the answer to zoom a page with pinch. I didn't try with iframe

Answer (score 2):

In the native code just after this line

```
super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
```

Add this

```
WebSettings settings = super.appView.getSettings();
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
```

You'll need this in native part

```
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
```

And in the page you want to zoom, add this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes,initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=5, minimum-scale=0.25/>
```

This will allow you to zoom the whole page with pinch. Everything inside that page will be zoomed.

Comment: Nope. You will be able to control the zoom using meta tag. If you use ` <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/>` page won't be zoomed. And if you use the tag from the answer page will be zoomed. You can control zoom and zoom level by controlling initial-scale, minimum0scale,maximum-scale,user-scalable

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it isn't scaling.  I am getting zoom manager messages in the log showing scale changes, but nothing on the page is changing

Comment: Which android version you are using?

Comment: If you're using bigger than version HONEYCOMB, then drop these line and try again. `settings.setDisplayZoomControls(true); settings.setSupportZoom(true);`

Comment: Still nothing... I am using onsen UI, could that be getting in the way?

Comment: Didn't use ONSEN UI, so can't tell