# How to implement pinch/zoom in Phonegap + jQueryMobile for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, pinchzoom

I have a phonegap app where I want users to be able to pinch on images and zoom in and out. I only want them to zoom in and out on the images, not the rest of the app, that is why I have the viewport meta tag set to no scale:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
```

I've been researching but don't find a clear good solution to implement this. The packages I have found look old and not actively maintained.

How can I let users pinch and zoom on certain page elements only?

I am using Cordova 3.5, and jQueryMobile 1.3 .

Thanks!

Comment: I have used hammer.js to respond to pinch gestures: http://hammerjs.github.io/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24389605/50447