# Mobile: If the html page is not user-scalable in the meta tag, how can I make its child iframe be user-scalable?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, mobile

I understand that if the parent page is not user-scalable, the iframe child (that contains another html page) will not be user-scalable regardless.  ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678454/allow-zooming-within-iframe-but-not-on-page-in-ios).)

In my project the iframe just contains an html page showing an image, and I want the pinch-zoom functionality to take effect on it. What javascript/jQuery tricks are there as a workaround for this?